Specify the Anaconda base location when installing
I am trying to install Anaconda on a remote server. When installing, anaconda will always try to create .conda directory under /home/username/, even though I already specific the install location using -u /path/to/desire/location. Due to the remote server safety policies, my home directory is /some/where/directory, instead of /home/username/. I have no permission accessing or doing something under the original /home/user.
So every installation is ended with Unpacking payload ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/username/.conda’: Disk quota exceeded
Which means the installation fails. To solve this, I guess I need to specify the base .conda location before the installation.
Is there anyway to specific the Anaconda base install location when installing?
First: I try install with the command ./Anaconda-install-script.sh. When Anaconda asking for install location, I enter /path/to/desire/location, but ended with the result shown above.
Second: I try to innstall with options ./Anaconda-install-script.sh -u /path/to/desire/location, ended with same result as First.
I guess -u only specific the install location, not the base location. There must be some way to tell Anaconda install script to create .conda directory under /path/to/desire/location, like setting alias or soft link, or just doing a export command.

I think you need the options pkg_dirs and envs_dirs that are used to configure Conda when you run it  after installation. You can read the documentation here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/settings.html#envs-dirs-specify-environment-directories
